# jBPM 7.6.0 getting started workbench tutorial - unable to complete form

Tags: jbpm, evaluation

I am new to jBPM, starting with version 7.6.  I watched the "10-Minute Tutorial using the Workbench", and tried to follow along.

Aside from the video having no sound and appearing to be for an earlier version of jBPM (significant console design changes), I was able to follow it.  However, when it comes to completing the "self-evaluation" form, after I Claimed and then Started the task, the Performance field is enabled, but does not allow me to type anything into it.

Is this a known issue?  I've tried with both Chrome and Firefox with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and found out in newer version, it only accepts number :)

Answer (score 0):

Yasser is correct. The 7.7.0 documentation / tutorials is out of date in quite a few topics.